# Is there a way in JavaScript to recognize when a browser is loading a page?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to check users leave a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1619930/how-to-check-users-leave-a-page)

For example when somebody refreshes, enters a new URL into the location bar, or navigates away using a link on the page?

I need to do some work after someone attempts to leave my page.

EDIT: onunload doesn't work because in most browsers that doesn't execute until the page they are attempting to leave to returns a response. I want to execute some code as soon as they attempt to leave.

beforeunload appears to work, but I'm not sure a beforeunload without a return is proper form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use window.onunload which will be executed when the window is unloaded, which also includes navigating to a different page.

```
window.onunload=function () {  };
```

I am not sure about what you are trying to do, but check

[window.onbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onbeforeunload) @ MDN and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536907%28VS.85%29.aspx

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
  e = e || window.event;

  // For IE and Firefox prior to version 4
  if (e) {
    e.returnValue = 'Any string';
  }

  // For Safari
  return 'Any string';
};
```

FYI. Comment out the return if you don't want user to see the Leave Page/Stay on Page prompt.

Comment: I want code to execute as soon as they attempt to leave the page, not once the page they are trying to leave to returns a response.

Comment: Didn't realize beforeunload could be used without a return. Interesting. How cross browser is that event?

Answer (score 2):

window.onunload, [here's docs from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onunload), this is the event raised when the document is unloaded.

Comment: I want code to execute as soon as they attempt to leave the page, not once the page they are trying to leave to returns a response.