# How to detect if they left the Webpage?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to be able to know if the user minimized the webpage or went to another Tab in their browser, Is that possible?

Comment: This might be of help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/147636/best-way-to-detect-when-user-leaves-a-web-page

Comment: Short answer: yes, it is possible. Maybe you could describe what you're trying to accomplish - chances are, it would make for horrible usability.

Comment: @Mahesh: The titles are similar, but from the question body, the OP is asking something different.

Comment: @Matt: Agreed, suggesting similar cases.

Answer (score 0):

Afraid not, the closest you can get is blur/focus on the window object like this:

```
$(window).blur(function() { console.log('left'); });
$(window).focus(function() { console.log('came back'); });
```

Comment: You should mention this uses jQuery. In general, you won't get a positive reaction from assuming that a jQuery answer is acceptable.