# How to update mysql table row every two minutes?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql members table. It have a column name of "lastonline". I want to update this column every two minutes in PHP. I think it would be possible through ajax time interval.Please advise me how to achieve this easily?

Comment: You are doing it *all* wrong. This is a horrendous idea.

Comment: is it ajax question or mysql question?

Answer (score 2):

If you're creating an AJAX application, you can simply log a "last_online" column that gets updated with a date every time the user request a page (either via AJAX or HTTP).

If you must do this with AJAX, Prototype offers a [PeriodicalExecutor](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/periodicalExecuter) that you can use to send requests at a predefined interval:

Answer (score 0):

I do not recommend to do it via ajax, but to write a scritp ad hoc and run a cron every 10 minutes and you are upgrading.

Comment: sorry i want every 2 mins not every 2 secs. Please refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7964903/how-to-get-currently-logged-users-in-mysql. I want to know who are currently online

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you you update the "lastonly" column with every request a user makes? Do you really need the two-second resolution?.