# activate events onclick of browser's back button in jquery

Tags: jquery

Im looking for a simple cross-browser plugin or method that can help me do this :

```
$('#clear_window').click(function(){
    $('#window').fadeOut(50);
        var activeTab = $("ul.tabs li.active").find("a").attr("href");
        $(activeTab).fadeIn(50);
});
```

but on the click of the browsers back button not on the #clear_window click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can through [HTML5 History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onpopstate). But this only supported by Gecko (Firefox), Chrome and **Internet Explorer 10+**

For what you want you can [read it in MDN documentation.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onpopstate)

However, if you can how your application handle your URLs, then you can implement it through the hashchange event, similar to how this [jQuery plugin](http://tkyk.github.com/jquery-history-plugin/) handles it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot detect broswer's back button click.
The only way to do is to detect "leave page" event.
This might help...
[Best way to detect when a user leaves a web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147636/best-way-to-detect-when-user-leaves-a-web-page)