# Displaying a confirm dialog box when the user tries to refresh/close/navigate to another web page

Tags: javascript

I would like to warn the user with a confirm dialog box when he tries to refresh the page, navigate to another page, close the page.

Just like Gmail does; for example when you write something then try to close the page without sending your message, a warning dialog box will appear with two options:
Leave this page/Stay on this page

Comment: Check this thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/147636/best-way-to-detect-when-user-leaves-a-web-page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use onbeforeunload. From https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onbeforeunload:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
  e = e || window.event;

  // For IE and Firefox prior to version 4
  if (e) {
    e.returnValue = 'Your text';
  }

  // For others
  return 'Your text';
};
```