# prevent default behavior not working

Tags: javascript

I am trying to prevent the default action for a dynamic image gallery without a JavaScript library like jQuery. Here is the project - http://the-session.co.uk/JSgallery/ It seems the links are still taking the user to the destination of the link when I do not want them too. I have am using the inline event handler `onclick` in my HTML markup to invoke the function.

```
<a href="images/tuco.jpg" onclick="showPic(this)" title="Tuco">Tuco Salamanca</a>
```

The function:

```
function showPic(whichpic) { 

    var source = whichpic.getAttribute("href");  
    var placeholder = document.getElementById("placeholder"); 
    placeholder.setAttribute("src",source); 

    var event = window.event;
    if(event.preventDefault) {
        event.preventDefault(); // handles most browsers
    }
    else {
        return false;          // handles ie
    }
}
```

This error is displayed for a split second in the console when the mouse is clicked:

[image]

Now surely event has been defined on the line above: `var event = window.event;` Any suggestions to resolve the problem?

Comment: The line `var event = window.event;` will only work in IE. Better use not the inline event handler approach but `theElem.onclick=function(evt) { var e = window.event || evt }`

Answer (score 2):

The object `window.event` only exists in Internet Explorer and not other browsers.

In other browsers, the event is passed in as a parameter to the function that is handling the event.

What you really want is something like:

```
<a href="images/tuco.jpg" onclick="showPic(event)" title="Tuco">Tuco Salamanca</a>
```

And

```
function showPic(e) { 

    if (!e) var e = window.event;

    var whichpic = e.target

    var source = whichpic.getAttribute("href");  
    var placeholder = document.getElementById("placeholder"); 
    placeholder.setAttribute("src",source); 

    if(e.preventDefault) {
        e.preventDefault(); // handles most browsers
    }
    else {
        return false;          // handles ie
    }
}
```

[Quirks Mode](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_access.html) has a great overview.

FWIW: Event handling normalization is one of the biggest advantages that comes with using a JavaScript library or framework. Take a look at jQuery, Dojo, Prototype, etc., etc.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `onclick` in an `href` you must follow the action with `return false;`, or the `href` will be followed once the `onclick` action is complete.

Instead of using `onclick` and inlining your events, consider using JavaScript's event handling based on `id`. I definitely recommend using a library such as jQuery. Event handling is trivial, like so...

```
$('#someid').click(function() { alert('hi') });
```

Even with native JavaScript, it's a much better practice than littering your HTML with `onclick`...

```
document.getElementById('someid').click = function() {
    alert('hi');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<a href="images/tuco.jpg" onclick="showPic(event,this)" title="Tuco">Tuco Salamanca</a>
```

and:

```
function showPic(event, whichpic) { 

    var source = whichpic.getAttribute("href");  
    var placeholder = document.getElementById("placeholder"); 
    placeholder.setAttribute("src",source); 

    if(event.preventDefault) {
        event.preventDefault(); // handles most browsers
    }
    else {
        return false;          // handles ie
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The window.event is probably undefined, which is why your variable is undefined.  See if this question helps resolve your problem: [Why FF says that window.event is undefined? (call function with added event listener)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9813445/why-ff-says-that-window-event-is-undefined-call-function-with-added-event-list)

Answer (score 0):

I've been having fun with a similar problem, and found that this solution works:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" />
</head>
<body>
<a id="mylink" href="http://www.stackoverflow.com/" target="_blank">Go to SO.</a>
<script>
var linkClicked = false;

window.onload = function()
{
    document.getElementById("mylink").onclick = function(e)
    {

        if (!e) var e = window.event;
        if (!linkClicked)
        {
            linkClicked = true;
            // Add code to change appearance of link so that people will know not to click it.

        }
        else
        {

                if(e.preventDefault) 
                {
                    e.preventDefault(); // handles most browsers
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;          // handles ie
                }
        }   
    }
}    
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

In this example, the link will work and open a new window once. All further clicks will have no effect.

I would recommend you add styling to make it obvious that the link no longer works.

I got help from Dancrumb's answer, so if you like this, like that too!