# Getting an error: TypeError: window.event is undefined in firefox for my javascript code

Tags: javascript

i am getting an error message on this code on Firefox browser

```
function num_press() 
{
var assumed = window.event.srcElement.value;
// alert (" assumed " + assumed);
if (pointPressed)
{
//alert (" fraction number" );
    currentNo = currentNo + (assumed * decimalPoint);
    decimalPoint = decimalPoint /10;
    document.calc_form.answer_tf.value = currentNo;
 } 
 else 
{
currentNo = (currentNo*10) + (assumed*1);
document.calc_form.answer_tf.value = currentNo;
}
}
```

I am only getting an error in Firefox, but works in safari and IE.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9813445/why-ff-says-that-window-event-is-undefined-call-function-with-added-event-list

Answer (score 3):

That's because Firefox doesn't have a `window.event`. Try something like this:

```
function num_press(e) 
{
var assumed = (e || window.event).srcElement.value;
```

In fact, it doesn't have a `srcElement` attribute either, so you would need to do something like this:

```
function num_press(e) 
{
var event = e || window.event
var assumed = (event.target || event.srcElement).value;
```