# JavaScript keydown event does not work

Tags: javascript

Here's my problem:
 I have 6 images:

```
<img class="img" src="key_1.png" />
<img class="img" src="key_2.png" />
<img class="img" src="key_3_5.png" />
<img class="img" src="key_4.png" />
<img class="img" src="key_3_5.png" />
<img class="img" src="key_6.png" />
```

What i want to do is that when i press the 'up' and 'down' arrow keys, the images rotate:

```
document.onkeydown = function () {
    switch (window.event.keyCode) {
    case 38:
        document.getElementsByClassName("img").style.webkitTransform = "rotate(7deg)"
        break;
    case 40:
        document.getElementsByClassName("img").style.webkitTransform = "rotate(-14deg)"
        break;
    }
};
```

But it won't work.

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9813445 `window.event` isn’t supported in modern browsers.

Comment: Also note the code you're developing is intrusive. Check this for a non intrusive way of implementing it using addEventListener/attachEvent: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2657182/correct-usage-of-addeventlistener-attachevent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will rotate all images 1deg clock/counter clockwise on every key press.

```js
var deg  = 0,
    $img = $( 'img' );

function rotateImages ( deg ) {  
  $img.css({
    '-webkit-transform': 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg )',
    '-moz-transform':    'rotate(' + deg + 'deg )',
    'transform':         'rotate(' + deg + 'deg )'
  });
}

$( document ).on( 'keydown', function ( e ) {
  e.preventDefault(); // Prevents the page from scrolling up/down
  
  switch( e.keyCode || e.which ) {
    case 38:
      deg++;
      rotateImages( deg );
      break;
      
    case 40:
      deg--;
      rotateImages( deg );
      break;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="http://store.storeimages.cdn-apple.com/4711/as-images.apple.com/is/image/AppleInc/aos/published/images/i/ph/iphone6/plus/iphone6-plus-box-space-gray-2014?wid=478&hei=595&fmt=jpeg&qlt=95&op_sharpen=0&resMode=bicub&op_usm=0.5,0.5,0,0&iccEmbed=0&layer=comp&.v=1411520743411" width="100">
<img src="http://store.storeimages.cdn-apple.com/4711/as-images.apple.com/is/image/AppleInc/aos/published/images/i/ph/iphone6/plus/iphone6-plus-box-space-gray-2014?wid=478&hei=595&fmt=jpeg&qlt=95&op_sharpen=0&resMode=bicub&op_usm=0.5,0.5,0,0&iccEmbed=0&layer=comp&.v=1411520743411" width="100">
<img src="http://store.storeimages.cdn-apple.com/4711/as-images.apple.com/is/image/AppleInc/aos/published/images/i/ph/iphone6/plus/iphone6-plus-box-space-gray-2014?wid=478&hei=595&fmt=jpeg&qlt=95&op_sharpen=0&resMode=bicub&op_usm=0.5,0.5,0,0&iccEmbed=0&layer=comp&.v=1411520743411" width="100">
```

Answer (score 2):

`event` should be passed as the parameter to the event handler. When an event occurs, the `event` object is passed as the parameter to the event handler. It is not global object so you cannot use it like `window.event`.

```js
var eventHandler = function(event) {
  console.log(event.keyCode);

  // Your code here
  switch (event.keyCode) {
    case 38:
      document.getElementsByClassName("img").style.webkitTransform = "rotate(7deg)"
      break;
    case 40:
      document.getElementsByClassName("img").style.webkitTransform = "rotate(-14deg)"
      break;
  }
};

document.addEventListener('keydown', eventHandler, false);
```

```html
<img class="img" src="key_1.png" />
<img class="img" src="key_2.png" />
<img class="img" src="key_3_5.png" />
<img class="img" src="key_4.png" />
<img class="img" src="key_3_5.png" />
<img class="img" src="key_6.png" />
```

Comment: @PraveenKumar Done. Was doing the same thing

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function rotate(deg) {
  var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('img');
  for(var i in elems) {
    var elem = elems[i];
    elem.style.webkitTransform = 'rotate('+deg+'deg)';
  }
}

document.onkeydown = function(event) {
    switch(event.keyCode) {
        case 38:
            rotate(7);
            break;
        case 40:
            rotate(-14);
            break;
    }
};
```

Running sample: http://plnkr.co/edit/RAg0wbwALTvT2tfzPumH?p=preview

Note that I had to rewrite the rotation as you were using getElementsByClassName that returns a list and not a single object, so you have to iterate it over.

Edit: Although check this for the "correct" non intrusive way of doing it with addEventListener:
http://plnkr.co/edit/FpYfow6Wmou8zGs483hc?p=preview