# event.target.id not working on firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I have a simple click function that does work fine on IE and Chrome but not on firefox. at first, it did not work at all till I put it inside doc.ready function. this example here works but on firefox it only displays the doc ready alert, and clickworking alert when clicked but no alert or action having to do with event.target.id

```html
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<p class="clickbtn" id="someclickbtn"> Click here </p>
<script type='text/javascript'>  
$(document).ready(function(){
 alert("doc ready");
$(".clickbtn").click(function() {
 alert("clickworking");
 alert(event.target.id);
 var targetid = "#" + event.target.id + "scroll";
 alert(targetid);
 $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(targetid).offset().top
    }, 1000);
})
});
</script>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you in advance

Comment: Pass an `event` to the `function()`?

Comment: If this is working in chrome and IE, maybe that browsers have a problem. If a variable (`event` in this case) is not defined, an error need to be throwing. If not, the browser have a problem. Firefox is working fine again :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why FF says that window.event is undefined? (call function with added event listener)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9813445/why-ff-says-that-window-event-is-undefined-call-function-with-added-event-list)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In firefox, you have to receive `event` object in your event handler,

```
$(".clickbtn").click(function(event) {
```

Chrome will not expect it to be received. But it is always good to receive it in your event handler.

Comment: Yes..Without argument, it will fail in `-moz-`..`this` could be used as well I suppose..

Comment: Cool, Thank you very much it worked right away, didn't realize you just had to add that 'event' in their

Comment: It's not only "good", it's per specs, `window.event` is not on a standard track, it's an IE proprietary property : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the `event` object as function's param.

This is the line:

```
$(".clickbtn").click(function(event) {
```

And here is the snippet:

```html
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<p class="clickbtn" id="someclickbtn"> Click here </p>
<script type='text/javascript'>  
$(document).ready(function(){
 alert("doc ready");
$(".clickbtn").click(function(event) {
 alert("clickworking");
 alert(event.target.id);
 var targetid = "#" + event.target.id + "scroll";
 alert(targetid);
 $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(targetid).offset().top
    }, 1000);
})
});
</script>
```