# Javascript get event from this

Tags: javascript

I am trying to move from inline `onkeyup` event and changed my input from

```
<input name="some1" id="some1" onkeyup="ajax_autocomplete('some1',this.value,event);">
```

to

```
<input name="some1" id="some1" class="autoc">
```

and after page load

```
var acinputs = document.querySelectorAll('.autoc');
for(var i=0; field=acinputs[i]; i++) 
{
field.onkeyup = function() {update.call(this);}
    function update() 
    {
    var text = this.value;
    // How to get keycode now from event?
    // Before: var kc=event.which;if(kc==undefined){kc=event.keyCode}
    }
}
```

My problem is that while I was getting `event` data inline like `keycode` from the `event` before but I do not know how to get it from event now? `this.value` gives me the text entered in the `input` however `this.event` does not work! I know `this.event` is not the proper way of getting event from `this` !

I am **not** using jQuery.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you unable (or unwilling) to use jquery?

Comment: Jquery is great and does all the things http://i.stack.imgur.com/ssRUr.gif

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why FF says that window.event is undefined? (call function with added event listener)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9813445/why-ff-says-that-window-event-is-undefined-call-function-with-added-event-list)

Comment: I am bit unwilling to use jquery as I found it quite big file to do simple things in javascript + Jquery has a steep learning curve where you can do things without understanding javascript (and there lies the problem)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add event as parameter

In my example `event` is referred to `ev`.

```
field.onkeyup = function(ev) {update.call(this, ev);}

function update(th, ev) 
{
    var text = th.value;

    var kc=ev.which;
    if(kc==undefined) {
       kc=ev.keyCode
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just assign `update` to `onkeyup` and avoid the extra method call?

Comment: @mdickin This is just an reply to the OP. I do not have optimize the author code.

Comment: @mdickin You are right I removed the method `call` and assigned directly. Still experimenting and I copied that code from internet tutorial . Thanks again for the help.