# How to discard form changes on button click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

**Overview**:
I have an HTML form that contains 10 radio buttons and 3 text areas with the following 3 buttons:

**Enable Editing:** The form input fields are disabled in this case (form fields are enabled/disabled depending on status). This button will enable input fields and will allow changes to be made to the form.

**Save**: save data to DB.

**Cancel**: This should "Discard changes" made to the form and restores the original values.

**Note:** The form gets populated from the DB. On "cancel" click I would like to restore the old data if any changes were made.

**Issue**: How can I implement an onclick method that will store data temporarily when "enable editing" button is clicked and another method that would restore the old form data(discard changes) when the "Cancel" button is clicked ?

What I have tried so far after looking at a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10640355/how-to-discard-form-changes):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#evaluationFormEdit').click(function() {
    $('#evaluationForm').find(':input').each(function(i, elem) {
        var input = $(elem);
        input.data('initialState', input.val());
    });
});

function restore() {

    $('#evaluationForm').find(':input').each(function(i, elem) {
        var input = $(elem);
        input.val(input.data('initialState'));
    });
}

$('#evaluationFormEditCancel').click(function() {

    restore();
});
});
```

Comment: button type="reset" ?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I would like to restore the form to how it was before any changes were made and not to reset it completely.

Comment: fair enough - what's wrong with the code you posted?

Comment: @khalidalqahtani check link http://www.dorcode.com/answers.php?id=57&que=confirm-alert

Comment: I'm not completely sure but think it has something to do events handling. When I click on cancel nothing happens and I get no errors.

Comment: Just save your response from db to some local object and then bind it to the form and on cancel button click, just call the restore function where you just rebind the data to form from local object!

Comment: This would reset the form: $("#form-name").trigger('reset');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I replaced two line of code with

```
 $(this).data("previous-value", $(this).val());
```

I guss this will work for you. here is my demo http://jsfiddle.net/0qL8bky6/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#evaluationFormEdit').click(function() {
        $('#evaluationForm').find(':input').each(function(i, elem) {
          $(this).data("previous-value", $(this).val());
        });
    });

    function restore() {

        $('#evaluationForm').find(':input').each(function(i, elem) {
            $(this).val($(this).data("previous-value"));
        });
    }

    $('#evaluationFormEditCancel').click(function() {

        restore();
    });
    });
```

Comment: Thank you Ritz for the reply. How would you change this to make it work for both text fields and radio buttons(or even all input types) ?

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, save your old data by json variable and restore form when click "Cancel" button.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do that is you can create an array A and when you click on the enable editing button you can store all the value of the field on that array(A) and keys would be the ids of the fields and the value would the fields value, so when you want to put the old values in the fields you can run the each function and put the old values in to the corresponding fields with their respected ids.
Like-
if you have three input fields which have id input1, input2, input3
and when you click on the enable editing button you can do.

```
var a = [];
$('input[type=text]').each(function(){
    a.push({'input1':$('#input1').val(),'input2':$('#input2').val(),'input3':$('#input3').val()});
});
```

This will have all you old values and when you want to put the old values back to input fields you do like this.

```
$.each(a,function(key,data){
    $('#'+key).val(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
 $('#evaluationFormEditCancel').click(function() {
        $('#evaluationForm').find(':input').each(function(i, elem) {
        // uncheck all checkbox here to make it default.
            $(elem).val("");   
        });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but as I mentioned above I would like to restore the form with the old data and not reset the form completely.

Comment: Okay if you want to restore values to old values. you need to first store old values in var first. 

you can do this by using jquery change event.