# FCKEditor: Showing message box on click of a link in the CMS area

Tags: fckeditor

in my cms control that uses FCKEditor, I need to show a message box that says: you are leaving current page.
Is this possible?
If so then how?

Comment: See this question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/147636/best-way-to-detect-when-user-leaves-a-web-page

Comment: Thanks for quick reply.
However, in this case as defined in your link, by using onbeforeunload() user will get dialogue box even if he is trying to go to some page in the site only.
My issue is that I need to show the message only when user is trying to go to another page which has link in only CMS pages.