# Call a JavaScript Function when Back Button of Browser is Clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to detect when user leaves a web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147636/best-way-to-detect-when-user-leaves-a-web-page)

How can I call a javascript or jQuery function when back button of browser is clicked?
I have seen some solutions but none of them worked for me.
Can anybody show me some example code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/147636/best-way-to-detect-when-user-leaves-a-web-page

Comment: @ohaal: I can't remember, but did not work. Can u tell me the best way?

Comment: You cannot detect the back button. You can detect when the visitor is leaving using onbeforeunload and that is about it.

Answer (score 9):

In jQuery try this :

```
$(window).unload( function () 
{
// put your code here
});
```

In javascript :

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
   // put your code here
}
```

Comment: unload() event is not specific to browser's back button but thats answered the question so +1

Comment: unload event will even work if you submit or navigate to future pages.

Answer (score 1):

```
<body onUnload="yourFunction();>
<!-- ... -->
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`history.replaceState()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) ([see browser support](http://caniuse.com/#search=replacestate)) to modify the previous URL you visited to the current page with an added parameter of your choosing like for instance `redirect=<URL of previous actual previous page>` (you can maybe get this URL from the referer?), then detect the parameter in document ready and perform the required actions.

This is just an untested theory, I might elaborate later on when I get to test it.