# How to create a function that changes css when clicking go-back button in browser with JS/jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Lets say I want to go to the previous page in Chrome and I click "<-". Can I add an EventListener or some kind of function that activates when I click the button.

```
function goBack() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.overflow = "auto";
}
```

So in the example above. I want to call `goBack()` function when user goes to previous page that changes `body` overflow to `auto`.

When I searched how to solve this problem I only found instances on how to move back using `history.back()`.

Comment: Off of the top of my head, I could think of [`onBeforeUnload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Call a JavaScript Function when Back Button of Browser is Clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12970627/call-a-javascript-function-when-back-button-of-browser-is-clicked)

Comment: I don't think you can, because if you click the back button the browser loads a different page unless you will use History API. If that is the case you can use History API to listen to the change URL events.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible. You could actually do this in either jQuery or plain JavaScript, based on your preference.

Here is how you would do it in jQuery:

```js
$(window).unload(goBack);
```

Alternatively, here is javascript:

```js
window.onbeforeunload = goBack;
```

That should do it!

Comment: you're calling the function (`goBack()`) instead of assigning it.

Comment: Sorry, fixed that.

Comment: still broken in jquery example

Comment: oof im not good at this -_-

Comment: no one's perfect, no worries