# What would be a good interval to send "still online" pings to a PHP webserver?

Tags: php, web-applications, webserver

Users on my website can have friends, and friends can chat with each other. You can also set your status to online, away and busy.

If a user is no longer on the website, his status should be set to offline. I guess the best way to do this would be to send AJAX requests to the server at a regular interval, then automatically set the status to offline if the server stops receiving these messages.

However, what would be a good interval to send these messages? 5 seconds? 1 minute?

If it really depends on how capable the webserver is, is there a way to check with PHP? What would be example intervals for some frequently-used webserver capabilities?

Comment: I think it will depend on how accurate you want it to be. How much time do you want to let your users wait for a new update. For a chat session 15-30 secs seems ok to me. There is no definite answer to this question.

Comment: I would do it the other way around. Send a XHR to set his/het status offline. And be sure to cover cases like browser crashes and switching pages `body onunload`. On the server side a session could expire.

Comment: @Bart I thought about sending an ajax request onbeforeunload, but then it could appear to flicker between offline and online.

Comment: Why would it flicker? If you send for example `http://localhost/status/john/offline` it should set the state and not toggle between them.

Comment: If you would go to another page, but on the same website, it'd call onbeforeunload, while it's actually just switching pages. (The friendslist is visible on (almost) all pages)

Answer (score 2):

I would consider using this >> http://www.bedroomlan.org/coding/detecting-%E2%80%98idle%E2%80%99-and-%E2%80%98away%E2%80%99-timeouts-javascript

Then modify the following:

```
setIdleTimeout(2000); // 2 seconds
setAwayTimeout(4000); // 4 seconds
document.onIdle = function() {$('#div_idle').css('opacity', '1');}
document.onAway = function() {$('#div_away').css('opacity', '1');}
document.onBack = function(isIdle, isAway) {
    if (isIdle) $('#div_idle').css('opacity', '0.2');
    if (isAway) $('#div_away').css('opacity', '0.2');
}
```

to something like:

```
setIdleTimeout(120000); // Make these two 
setAwayTimeout(360000); // a lot longer
document.onIdle = function() {
    // your ajax calls for when they go
}
document.onAway = function() {
    // code here to maybe log them out or what ever you wish to do via ajax.
}
document.onBack = function(isIdle, isAway) {
    // code here for when they return
}
```

This way you cut down on the requests.

QUICK EDIT:

Logging out when closing the browser can be achieved via jQuery .unload():

```
$(window).unload(function() {
  // ajax call when they just go, like they don't even care!
});
```

Comment: Sessions and cookies that expire can also help along side this script.

Comment: What if the user leaves the page, or the browser crashes? It wouldn't set the status to offline then.

Comment: Sorry. If using jQuery you can use: http://api.jquery.com/unload/

Comment: And here that topic is discussed using JavaScript: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/147636/best-way-to-detect-when-a-user-leaves-a-web-page

Answer (score 2):

This is really more of a usability/expectations question than a coding problem.  If the load on the server isn't very high, these aren't even going to be noticeable.  I doubt you'd need to check every 5 seconds, but it is probably feasible, especially if it's just a personal site with a limited number of users.  In high load conditions, you'd probably make it substantially higher.

Comment: I guess I'll just start at 5 seconds and see how it works out then.