# Execute some function when closing browser

Tags: javascript

I want to know how to execute some function when I close my browser... so the detail is I making website that going to sell items and the scenario is user login to my website and then they select some items that will put into shopping cart and when user closing browser then they account shopping cart will be empty, how to do that? I mean I already know how to clean the shopping cart but I don't know how to execute this function when closing browser

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to detect when a user leaves a web page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/147636/best-way-to-detect-when-a-user-leaves-a-web-page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e){
//Do some thing here
};
```

Find more info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.onbeforeunload)

Comment: This works but it will override any existing handlers. Consider using: window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function(event) { 
/* your code */ 
});

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely a duplicated question. Please have a look at `onbeforeunload` Javascript event.

Reference:

- [Best way to detect when a user leaves a web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147636/best-way-to-detect-when-a-user-leaves-a-web-page)
- [Mozilla Develper page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.onbeforeunload?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Fwindow.onbeforeunload)

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery unload for that: http://api.jquery.com/unload/

Comment: From the `javascript` tag description: *"Unless a tag for a framework/library is also included, a pure JavaScript answer is expected."*

Comment: Thank you Felix, I'll take that into account in the future!

Answer (score -1):

This will add a new handler:

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function(event) { 
/* your code */ 
});
```

If you use:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e){
//Do some thing here
};
```

This will override any existing handlers and replace it with your own.