# javascript php execute database script(AJAX) on page leaving

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I've got the following issue:

**I'd like to execute an AJAX request through JS, which would call the mysql query and clear some data in database(UPDATE and stuff,whatever) when user is leaving my web page.**

Does anyone have any ideas how to do such thing?

I mean I'm only missing one piece of the whole process: JavaScript function(event or something).

Comment: Take a look at the `onbeforeunload` event - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.onbeforeunload

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to detect when a user leaves a web page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/147636/best-way-to-detect-when-a-user-leaves-a-web-page)

Comment: Sorry guys!I saw that topic but I thought it was only about asking if user is sure to leave, which was not what I was lookin' for. Anyone who see this and is powerful enough here, should go ahead and remove the whole topic or something. Thanks btw(it works).

Comment: I tried to determine when a user left a page a while back, and I don't believe you can guarantee the code will always get triggered. Certainly with Chrome I believe there is a problem, we had users losing data keyed into Ckeditor that was lost when Chrome decided to do a background update and reload the browser.