# Do something when user leaves current page or tab

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the code below to check when the user changes the current tab.
It works great but how can i run a jquery code insted changing the document title?
I am trying to display a box when the user leaves the current tab/page and when the user come back to see it.

```
<script>
var vis = (function(){
    var stateKey, eventKey, keys = {
        hidden: "visibilitychange",
        webkitHidden: "webkitvisibilitychange",
        mozHidden: "mozvisibilitychange",
        msHidden: "msvisibilitychange"
    };
    for (stateKey in keys) {
        if (stateKey in document) {
            eventKey = keys[stateKey];
            break;
        }
    }
    return function(c) {
        if (c) document.addEventListener(eventKey, c);
        return !document[stateKey];
    }
})();

vis(function(){
  document.title = vis() ? 'Visible' : 'Not visible';


//I tried

   $('.alertbox').show();

});
</script>

<div class="alertbox" style="display:none;">Welcome Back</a>
```

check this out: http://daniemon.com/tech/webapps/page-visibility/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to detect when a user leaves a web page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/147636/best-way-to-detect-when-a-user-leaves-a-web-page)

Comment: And save/load a cookie to register when the user comes back to that page.

Comment: onbeforeunload only works when the page is closed completely (unloaded) am I wrong? And popular browsers do not run JS while the tab is not active. I have not a clue to do such a thing.

Comment: could also try catching window blur event

Comment: hey guys... check the link that i posted

Comment: And ofcourse it's not a duplicate question... I don't want to ask user if wants to leave the page.. instead to run a function or execute a jquery