# How to detect "leave a page" exactly if user opens other page in new tab?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I wanna exploit a special case when user `leaves a page`. I create a method to `do something` when user leaves a page. But, if user is staying on this page, and clicks a link to open new page in new tab. So, does user leave page?

Can you tell me a hint? Thank you!

p/s: I'm using MVC 5 and I can use jQuery/javascript.

Comment: @vinayakj No. I want to clear all temporary data if user leaves `this page` truly. But, if user opens other page in new tab, the temporary data won't be cleared.

Comment: Does "leaves this page" mean when the user _closes_ the tab?

Comment: save the the data in `localStorage`, whenever page loads get the data from `localStorage` and store it in some local variable, and on `onbeforeunload` clear it

Comment: @Vohuman Yes. `leaves this page` means user `closes` this page or clicks `back` button. But if user opens a page in new tab, that doesn't mean `leaves this page`. Because he doesn't `closes` the page or clicks `back` button.

Comment: If this is the case the question is duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888902/javascript-detect-browser-close-tab-close-browser). I'll reopen the question.

Comment: Using 'onunload' event, details in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/147636/best-way-to-detect-when-a-user-leaves-a-web-page?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 0):

You can't detect opening a new window or tab, but you can listen for the `'onunload'` event.

```
jQuery(window).bind("unload", function() {
    //your code here
});
```

This should fire when clicking on a link, closing the tab/window or pressing the back button.