# Idiomatic way to handle website closed/leave page events with React/React Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, redux

I want to send a cleanup request to my API sever when the user leaves the website (actually closes the tab/browser, not just changes page in the SPA). Is there an idiomatic way to do this in an app using React with React Router? Will componentWillUnmount fire on page close? I assume not.

Answer (score 3):

React doesn't do any special thing here for you. Just do that you usually do for this. Also, see answers to [a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147636/best-way-to-detect-when-a-user-leaves-a-web-page)

The best place to put this subscription code is the `componentDidMount` lifecycle method. And do not forget to unsubscribe it on `componentWillUnmount` to prevent leaks.

Comment: Thank you very much, this solved my same issue by adding `window.onbeforeunload = this.function` in `componentDidMount` and `componentWillUnmount`