# Is it possible to detect malicious ads that redirect users?

Tags: javascript

So I'm getting complaints sometimes that users are being taken to phishing and or virus-spreading sites without clicking on anything.
I think this is caused by some malicious google ads triggering `window.location` and redirecting people. 
Is it possible to detect such action so I could log ad source?

P.S> srry just to clarify -> **is it possible to also detect the url where is user being taken** so we could discern malicios rediredcts from non-malicious?

Comment: Are you rendering any string input from users? That could be the source of your problem if not properly escaped. I don't think it's because of Google ads.

Comment: @zurfyx — What makes a stored XSS attack more likely than the malicious ad hypothesis the OP has presented?

Comment: @Quentin I hope Google analyses its ads before displaying them

Comment: @zurfyx — You'd hope. They probably do. Plenty of malicious ones still seem to slip through. Especially on mobile.

Comment: @zurfyx no I don't render any user input.  This what Im talking about: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/chrome/HcXgFFaO9WU/SG6vrONDAAAJ. I've reported to google but they can't fix it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to detect when a user leaves a web page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/147636/best-way-to-detect-when-a-user-leaves-a-web-page)

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan srry to clarify -> for troubleshooting this I'd need to find out the destnation. The url where user is being taken as there might be many legitimate redirects: like user enters new url or clicks on the normal ad etc.

Comment: The answer to that is no. Think about it from a privacy/security point of view: why would I want some random site to know where I'm going when I'm leaving their site?

Answer (score 2):

You could quickly send some info about the page being redirected using `onbeforeunload`. You can either decide to block the redirection with a message asling a confirmation from the user, or just send to a backend some data about what happened.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(event) {
  // Send sync ajax call with event data
  // Return a message to ask confirmation
  return 'You are being redirected, please call the police'
};
```

Comment: is it possible to get a new destination address though? Because therewill be many legitimate uses as well afaik.

Answer (score 0):

To stop redirection you can try using `onbeforeunload` event

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
  var dialogText = 'Dialog text here';
  e.returnValue = dialogText;
  return dialogText;
};
```