# How to show popup when user tries to leave the page window or close the tab?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I used `onload="myFunction()"` on body tag,
And I used javascript code like this

```
function myFunction() {
  //alert("Page is loaded");
  document.getElementById("test").style.display = "block";
}

function hidePopup() {
  // alert("Hidden");
  document.getElementById("test").style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<div id="test" style="z-index: 20000;display: none;">
  <div id="popup">
    <div id="close" onclick="hidePopup()">x</div>
    <div id="popup_img" class="hos_modal" style="height:900px; width:900px; margin:0 auto;">
      <a href="javascript:void()" target="_blank"><img src="files/image.jpg" alt="free trial" style="width: auto; height: auto;"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The above code is showing popup when the browser is loaded. And I also used `onunload` and `onmouseout` events.

Comment: Check this http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/modal/

Comment: @Roy  Thanks for reply, I want to do this using pure javascript.

Comment: I don't understand, you need the pop up show on the close tab? Where is the id of the tab? you need to trigger mouseenter event on the tab for show the popup

Comment: Can you please show the code of the tab? which tap where is the tab in your code?

Comment: your question is not clear, please explain what exactly you want? I dont know who up vote it even its not clear!!!

Comment: Have you tried to use the `$(window).unload(function() {
   //do stuff
});` function instead of the onload?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best way to detect when a user leaves a web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147636/best-way-to-detect-when-a-user-leaves-a-web-page)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the goal is to display a message to the user then the solution is a very simple fix.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
  alert("Wait don't go!");
  return false;
}
```

returning false with this event handler allows you to create a popup message with `alert("");` and prevents the user from leaving the page until they click a confirmation

Answer (score 0):

Try this code probably will be helpful.

**Note**: If you also want to use  the function `onmouseout` just remove the comments in the respective lines

```js
function hidePopup() {
  // alert("Hidden");
  document.getElementById("test").style.display = "none";
}

window.onload = function() {
  console.log('window - onload');

};

document.getElementById("tab_3").addEventListener("mouseover", mouseOver);
// document.getElementById("tab_3").addEventListener("mouseout", mouseOut);

function mouseOver() {
  console.log('window - onmouseover');
  document.getElementById("test").style.display = "block";
}

//function mouseOut() {
  //console.log('window - onmouseout');
  //document.getElementById("test").style.display = "none";
//}
```

```css
/* Style the tab */

div.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}


/* Style the links inside the tab */

div.tab a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}


/* Change background color of links on hover */

div.tab a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}


/* Create an active/current tablink class */

div.tab a:focus,
.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}


/* Style the tab content */

.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab">
  <a id="tab_1" href="#" class="tablinks">Simple Tab</a>
  <a id="tab_2" href="#" class="tablinks">Simple Tab 2</a>
  <a id="tab_3" href="#" class="tablinks" onmouseover="mouseOver()" onmouseout="mouseOut()">Triggerer Tab</a>
</div>



<div id="London" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>London</h3>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>

<div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Paris</h3>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p>
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>

<div id="test" style="z-index: 20000;display: none;">
  <div id="popup">
    <div id="close" onclick="hidePopup()">x</div>
    <div id="popup_img" class="hos_modal" style="height:900px; width:900px; margin:0 auto;">
      <a href="javascript:void()" target="_blank">
        <img src="http://sit-stand.com/img/cms/animation1.gif" alt="free trial" style="width: auto; height: auto;"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```