# How to call a java method when i click the Browser forward or backward button

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, methods, browser

I have an requirement where i want to call a java method when i click the browser forward or backward button.
Previously I implement the same by using **Jquery** and **JavaScript**,found easy to implement the same.Here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147636/best-way-to-detect-when-a-user-leaves-a-web-page)
But now my requirement is to do the same by executing a java method.And in this java method i will execute my own Business requirement.

## My previous JavaScript code to implement the same is attached below

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
  ........
  ......
}
```

## My previous JQuery code to implement the same is attached below

```
window.userInteractionTimeout = null;
window.userInteractionInHTMLArea = false;
window.onBrowserHistoryButtonClicked = null; // This will be your event handler for browser navigation buttons clicked

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).mousedown(function () {
        clearTimeout(window.userInteractionTimeout);
        window.userInteractionInHTMLArea = true;
        window.userInteractionTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
            window.userInteractionInHTMLArea = false;
        }, 500);
    });

$(document).keydown(function () {
        clearTimeout(window.userInteractionTimeout);
        window.userInteractionInHTMLArea = true;
        window.userInteractionTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
            window.userInteractionInHTMLArea = false;
        }, 500);
    });

    if (window.history && window.history.pushState) {
        $(window).on('popstate', function () {
            if (!window.userInteractionInHTMLArea) {
                // alert('Browser Back or Forward button was pressed.');
                 }
    if(window.onBrowserHistoryButtonClicked ){
    window.onBrowserHistoryButtonClicked ();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

**I am using the following java version**

1. Java 1.8
2. Eclipse IDE
3. Maven

Any help is highly appreciated, all the best in advance,Good Luck!!!

Comment: You can still use javascript or jquery...just make an ajax call to trigger your java code.

Comment: Have you looked at:  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/prog_guide/javascript.html ?