# How to get the "Leave site? Changes that you made may not be saved" when trying to close a window with a populated form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form that when filled in, I can exit the window without being given a warning (I'm using Chrome).

How can I ensure I get a warning before exiting? Is there a Django setting for this?

Comment: sounds more like JS territory.

Comment: Django is server side. It doesn’t know what form data has or hasn’t been entered by a user until the form is submitted. This is a client side problem, and would require JavaScript.

Comment: JavaScript on close alert

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best way to detect when a user leaves a web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147636/best-way-to-detect-when-a-user-leaves-a-web-page)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to supply a function returning a string to `onbeforeunload` of the window or the document body in order to trigger the "Leave site" popup.

```js
window.onbeforeunload = () => '';
```

```html
<a href="http://example.com">Click to trigger</a>
```

Comment: Getting this error when I paste in my js file: https://i.imgur.com/RzGwvyt.png any idea?

Comment: Nevermind it is working. However are you able to tell me how I can only summon the popup when the form is not empty? currently it pops up every time I navigate away from any page...

Comment: You can add a condition to check if any of the form input is empty then return a string else return null

Comment: Probably you had that because your editor does not support arrow functions. In my editor, for example, I can choose compatible javascript standard. I assume you have something similar.

Answer (score 3):

The event is called beforeunload, so you can assign a function to window.onbeforeunload