# How to determine if a user leaves a page?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

so I've seen other posts about this issue but got only answer for leaving a page on purpose (i.e clicking the red X button on the corner).

How can I determine and make actions if a user leaves a page not on purpose (I mean like : internet disconnect / computer got shutdown...)

Thanks to all

Comment: You could try including some JavaScript in your page: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5893539/6589412

Comment: What exactly are you looking to do in response to the user leaving the page like this?  Things like losing network connectivity or power failure generally aren't events that would trigger something.  There's always going to be users who just drop off quietly.  Perhaps you're looking for a session timeout or something of that nature?

Comment: I mean, let's say I want to view a list of people currently in the page. Upon leaving the page, the name of the user will be erased from the list.